# Could not found kotlinx-atomicfu Compose Multiplatform iOS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I am trying to build the project that I have cloned from the repository *compose-multiplatform-ios-android-template* of JetBrains.
The code was running fine on Android but throws an error on iOS. I also tried to update the cocoapods. Still, this gives an error. Now when I try to build the project on **Android Studio** this gives the below error on my logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: e: Could not find "../shared/build/kotlinTransformedMetadataLibraries/commonMain/org.jetbrains.kotlinx-atomicfu-0.17.3-nativeInterop-8G5yng.klib" in [/Users/rasel/Library/Application Support/kotlin/daemon]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.SingleFileResolveKt$resolveSingleFileKlib$1.fatal(SingleFileResolve.kt:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.KotlinLibrarySearchPathResolver.resolve(SearchPathResolver.kt:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.KotlinLibrarySearchPathResolver.resolve(SearchPathResolver.kt:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.CompilerSingleFileKlibResolveStrategy.resolve(SearchPathResolver.kt:298)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.SingleFileResolveKt.resolveSingleFileKlib(SingleFileResolve.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.library.SingleFileResolveKt.resolveSingleFileKlib$default(SingleFileResolve.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.KlibMetadataDependencyContainer.<init>(K2MetadataKlibSerializer.kt:117)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataKlibSerializer$serialize$analyzer$1.invoke(K2MetadataKlibSerializer.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataKlibSerializer$serialize$analyzer$1.invoke(K2MetadataKlibSerializer.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.CommonAnalysisKt.runCommonAnalysisForSerialization(CommonAnalysis.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataKlibSerializer.serialize(K2MetadataKlibSerializer.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataCompiler.doExecute(K2MetadataCompiler.kt:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.metadata.K2MetadataCompiler.doExecute(K2MetadataCompiler.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1486)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Errors were stored into ../.gradle/kotlin/errors/errors-1686806929950.log
```

Is there any workaround for it?

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding multiple times and was expecting the build to success. But unfortunately it fails every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

apparently this happens often, you will need to go to your `build.gradle.kts` and add the following there as a workaround for the moment

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Use the same version in the error
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu-gradle-plugin:0.17.3")
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "kotlinx-atomicfu")    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, I have already solved the problem 5 days ago with the answer from below link which is same as yours. So also accepting yours. https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/12093271/hi-folks-i-am-trying-to-run-the-kmm-compose-multiplatform-pr#1aebb3a5-2e7e-4dd6-973c-f5763e1559a3

Answer (score 0):

I had to add following dependency in commonMain of shared module (or it could be any module giving the specified error) for this error to be solved, the plugin didn't work for me:

> implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu:0.20.2")