# Compose Multiplatform - gradle plugins build errors

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

My Compose Multiplatform project with SQLDelight DB fails to build without **kotlinx-atomicfu** plugin, but when it's active it clashes with **sqldelight** plugin. At the same time I'm able to just run it on Emulator, so the issue appears only during the rebuild process.

At the beginning I get an error mentioned [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76479563/could-not-found-kotlinx-atomicfu-compose-multiplatform-ios)

`e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: e: Could not find "../shared/build/kotlinTransformedMetadataLibraries/commonMain/org.jetbrains.kotlinx-atomicfu-0.17.3-nativeInterop-8G5yng.klib" in [/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/kotlin/daemon]`

The solution for it is to add several lines in a top-level build.gradle.kts with **kotlinx-atomicfu** dependency

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Use the same version in the error
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu-gradle-plugin:0.17.3")
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "kotlinx-atomicfu")    
}
```

After adding this block the build proceeds further, but then fails with several errors in MainViewController at **shared/iosMain**

```
package com.user.kmmtutorial

import androidx.compose.ui.window.ComposeUIViewController

fun MainViewController() = ComposeUIViewController {
    App()
}
```

errors:

```
ERROR: Exception while analyzing expression in (6,5) in ../shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/com/user/kmmtutorial/MainViewController.kt
Attachments:
causeThrowable
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeFqNamesKt$makeComposableAnnotation$1.getType(ComposeFqNames.kt:148)
(...)

Exception while analyzing expression in (6,5) in ../shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/com/user/kmmtutorial/MainViewController.kt

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.inference.components.ConstraintSystemCompletionContext.analyzeArgumentWithFixedParameterTypes(ConstraintSystemCompletionContext.kt:54)
(...)
expression.kt
File name: MainViewController.kt Physical: true Injected: false
fun MainViewController() = ComposeUIViewController {
    <caret>App()
}

org.jetbrains.kotlin.utils.KotlinExceptionWithAttachments: Exception while analyzing expression in (6,5) in ../shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/com/user/kmmtutorial/MainViewController.kt
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.logOrThrowException(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:253)

org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression in (6,5) in ../shared/src/iosMain/kotlin/com/user/kmmtutorial/MainViewController.kt

Attachments:
causeThrowable
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeFqNamesKt$makeComposableAnnotation$1.getType(ComposeFqNames.kt:148)
```

After some investigations I found out that disabling sqldelight plugin in **build.gradle.kts (:shared)** makes this issue disappear, so seems like it's kind of clashing with **kotlinx-atomicfu**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
//    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}
```

Summarizing: I'm able to run my Compose Multiplatform directly on Emulator, but each time I try to rebuild it it fails. So seems like I get errors without **kotlinx-atomicfu** plugin active, but when it's included my project fails with **sqldelight** plugin active. I've tried to use newer version of the **sqldelight**, but the most recent one uses kotlin version that is not yet supported in current Compose Multiplatform.

I've found similar issue appearing in [Philipp Lackner's Compose Multiplatform tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZxBUd2TbVGk?t=679), but he mentioned that this issue doesn't affect a build process

Comment: Please create issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: Im getting similar error but for "com.squareup.okio:okio:3.5.0"